# Deploy docker image into GCP GKE using Terraform

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

I am writing a terraform file in GCP to run a stateless application on a GKE, these are the steps I'm trying to get into terraform.

1. Create a service account
2. Grant roles to the service account
3. Creating the cluster
4. Configuring the deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mllp-adapter-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mllp-adapter
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mllp-adapter
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mllp-adapter
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          image: gcr.io/cloud-healthcare-containers/mllp-adapter
          ports:
            - containerPort: 2575
              protocol: TCP
              name: "port"
          command:
            - "/usr/mllp_adapter/mllp_adapter"
            - "--port=2575"
            - "--hl7_v2_project_id=PROJECT_ID"
            - "--hl7_v2_location_id=LOCATION"
            - "--hl7_v2_dataset_id=DATASET_ID"
            - "--hl7_v2_store_id=HL7V2_STORE_ID"
            - "--api_addr_prefix=https://healthcare.googleapis.com:443/v1"
            - "--logtostderr"
            - "--receiver_ip=0.0.0.0"
```

5. Add internal load balancer to make it accesible outside of the cluster

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mllp-adapter-service
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: port
    port: 2575
    targetPort: 2575
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: mllp-adapter
```

I've found this [example](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-kubernetes-engine/tree/master/examples/simple_autopilot_public) in order to create an auto-pilot-public cluster, however I don't know where to specify the YAML file of my step 4

Also I've found this other [blueprint](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-kubernetes-engine/tree/master/examples/deploy_service) that deploy a service to the created cluster using the kubernetes provider, which I hope solves my step 5.

I'm new at terraform and GCP architecture in general, I got all of this working following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/healthcare-api/docs/how-tos/mllp-adapter) however I'm now trying to find a way to deploy this on a dev enviroment for testing purposes but that's outside of my sandbox and it's supposed to be deployed using terraform, I think I'm getting close to it.

Can someone enlight me what's the next step or how to add those YAML configurations to the `.tf` examples I've found?

Am I doing this right? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this script and extend it further to deploy the YAML files with that : https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-kubernetes-engine/tree/master/examples/simple_autopilot_public

The above TF script is creating the GKE auto pilot cluster for YAML deployment you can use the K8s provider and apply the files using that.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/deployment

Full example : https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-kubernetes-engine/tree/master/examples/simple_autopilot_public

main.tf

```
locals {
  cluster_type           = "simple-autopilot-public"
  network_name           = "simple-autopilot-public-network"
  subnet_name            = "simple-autopilot-public-subnet"
  master_auth_subnetwork = "simple-autopilot-public-master-subnet"
  pods_range_name        = "ip-range-pods-simple-autopilot-public"
  svc_range_name         = "ip-range-svc-simple-autopilot-public"
  subnet_names           = [for subnet_self_link in module.gcp-network.subnets_self_links : split("/", subnet_self_link)[length(split("/", subnet_self_link)) - 1]]
}

data "google_client_config" "default" {}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = "https://${module.gke.endpoint}"
  token                  = data.google_client_config.default.access_token
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(module.gke.ca_certificate)
}

module "gke" {
  source                          = "../../modules/beta-autopilot-public-cluster/"
  project_id                      = var.project_id
  name                            = "${local.cluster_type}-cluster"
  regional                        = true
  region                          = var.region
  network                         = module.gcp-network.network_name
  subnetwork                      = local.subnet_names[index(module.gcp-network.subnets_names, local.subnet_name)]
  ip_range_pods                   = local.pods_range_name
  ip_range_services               = local.svc_range_name
  release_channel                 = "REGULAR"
  enable_vertical_pod_autoscaling = true
}
```

Another Good example which use the YAML files as template and apply it using the terraform. : https://github.com/epiphone/gke-terraform-example/tree/master/terraform/dev

Comment: Looks pretty straightforward! Thanks a lot